# Must scopes have revealing reflections?

Tags: military

This is my first post in *History*. I hope this is a good stack for my question, as I see a lot of posts related to military hardware. If not, well, let me know.

**Are there any documented cases of lens flares exposing sniper positions**? 
It's a movie trope that snipers are spotted because someone catches a glimpse of a reflection of the scope. It seems to me that this is a serious design flaw. How do I research whether this ever was a historical concern in the (evolution of) design of scopes?

My thought is this: Why is the frontmost (nearest the target) lens/glass so close to the end of the pipe (as in ╞═════╪╡)? Why isn't that piece of glass hidden *way* inside the pipe (as in ╞═════╪════╡)? That the *extra* bit of pipe could then block out any light/reflections apart from what is in the view of the shooter. It would also make the scope longer, but that can't be *that* much of a downside, can it?

If there *are* such "long scopes", how common are they? Or, put the other way around, given that reflections are undesired, how is this actually dealt with *outside of the movies*?

Comment: or maybe this questions is a better fit for the engineering stack?

Comment: They are called "anti-reflection devices" (ARDs) and there are several different types. One type has a honeycomb is only about a 1.5" wide. A shade tube will work as well.

Comment: @TylerDurden, if you change that comment to an answer, you could get some points soon...

Comment: By the way, [Olin mentioned](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/2188/1011) that this happened to the famous sniper Carlos Hathcock during his encounter with the enemy sniper "Cobra". Each knew the other was in the area. Hathcock saw a flash of light and fired at it. This turned out to be a reflection from Cobra's scope. The bullet went right thru the scope into Cobra's eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called "anti-reflection devices" (ARDs) and there are several different types. One type has a honeycomb and is only about a 1.5" wide. A shade tube will work as well.

[image: sniper scope ARD]

Comment: I wanna give you this answer before the question gets closed. Thanks!